# Finding the increment with the absolute function?

Tags: absolute-value

Let $K_1 = \left\| I_1 \right\|$ and $K_2 = \left\| I_2 \right\|$. Suppose $I_2 = I_1 + \Delta I$. Therefore:

$$\Delta K = K_2 - K_1 = \left\| I_1 + \Delta I\right\| - \left\| I_1 \right\|$$

Is there a way I can calculate $\Delta K$ without having to compute the sum of $I_1 + \Delta I$ ?

Edit:

As an example:

$
I_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.4 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.3 & -0.4 & -0.1 \\
-0.2 & -0.4 & 0.2
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$
\Delta I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

$K$ is calculated by taking the absolute values of a 2x2 submatrix of $I$. For example, $K_1$ is:

$
K_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1.3 & 0.8 \\
1.3 & 1.1
\end{pmatrix}
$

For example, the element at row 1, col 1 of $K_1$ is $\left\| -0.4 \right\| + \left\| 0.2 \right\| + \left\| 0.3 \right\| + \left\| -0.4 \right\| = 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4 = 1.3$.

The question now is how can I find $\Delta K$ given $I_1$ and $\Delta I$ without having to compute the sum of $I_1 + \Delta I$ ?

Comment: What are $I_1$ and $I_2$?

Comment: What are these $I$'s and $K$'s?  What does $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ mean?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be ΔK=$K_2-K_1$=$||I_2||-||I_1||$?

Comment: @5xum please check the updated post.

Comment: @saulspatz, please check the updated post.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, please check the updated post.

Comment: @ChadWinters Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  When you add $\Delta I$ to $I_1$ the central element changes from $-.4$ to $-.3$, so its absolute value decreases by $.1$.  All other elements are unchanged.  Because the central element belongs to every $2\times2$ matrix, each element of $\left\|I_1+\Delta I\right\|$ will be $.1$ less than the corresponding element of $\left\|I_1\right\|$.  That is $$\Delta K = \begin{pmatrix}-.1&-.1\\-.1&-.1\\\end{pmatrix}$$